# Setting Action animation length?

Tags: animation, auto-rig-pro

I used Auto-Rig Pro to rig a character. Now I want to make animations like Idle, Walk, Run etc. all in the same Blender file. I believe that the correct approach is to create a new Action for each animation clip. (If this isn't correct, please let me know!).

Assuming it is, I can't see how to set the length of each animation action. Most of them I want to loop, so I need to set the length so it can loop and I can check the animation is correct.

[image: Timeline is too long]

Comment: Each action will be as long as its last keyframe, for example if you push the action into the NLA, you'll see that the yellow strip will adapt to the action length. As for the Timeline length, I don't think that there's any automatic way to make it last as long as the selected action, you need to put the player cursor at the last keyframe and press Ctrl End, or type the End frame, or Playback > Set End Frame. Maybe it's possible with a script though

Comment: that said, you can temporarily frame the start and end with P, deactivate with Alt P

Comment: Ah I see, the ctrl+end is pretty easy and sets the length for Action Editor. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each action will be as long as its last keyframe, for example if you push the action into the *NLA*, you'll see that the yellow strip will adapt to the action length.

As for the Timeline length, I don't think that there's any automatic way to make it last as long as the selected action, you need to put the player cursor at the last keyframe and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>End</kbd>, or type the *End* frame, or *Playback > Set End Frame*:

[image]

Maybe it could be possible to synchronized the end of the timeline to the last keyframe with a script? I think it deserves a button.

that said, you can temporarily frame the start and end with <kbd>P</kbd>, deactivate with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>:

[image]